# What happens when @tf.function decorator compiles a function into graph? Why is it faster than that in eager mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

According to the TensorFlow [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/autograph), `@tf.function` compiles a function into a graph, and "makes you get the benefits of faster execution, running on GPU or TPU, or exporting to SavedModel."

The example in the document demonstrates such a benefit:

```
lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(10)

@tf.function
def lstm_fn(input, state):
  return lstm_cell(input, state)

input = tf.zeros([10, 10])
state = [tf.zeros([10, 10])] * 2
# warm up
lstm_cell(input, state); lstm_fn(input, state)
print("eager lstm:", timeit.timeit(lambda: lstm_cell(input, state), number=10))
print("function lstm:", timeit.timeit(lambda: lstm_fn(input, state), number=10))
```

output:

```
eager lstm: 0.032440788112580776 
function lstm: 0.004768412094563246
```

What's the difference between a 'compiled graph' and a 'function in eager mode'? Why is the former faster when executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager execution, used by default in TF 2.0, evaluates operations immediately, without building graphs. Graph on the other hand, has certain [advantages](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs#why_dataflow_graphs). However, execution time will depend on particular code. The more code uses c++ backend, the less the difference will be. All the overhead comes from program in eager mode using python interpreter. For example basic matrix multiplication operation will not get as much benefit as more complex DNN applications.

Answer (score 1):

In graph mode, TensorFlow builds a computation graph representing your model and forwards it to the C++ runtime via a Session. This provides distributed training benefits and optimizes your computation graph in the process(through constant folding, etc). It also eases the process of deploying to a platform-independent server.

The @tf.function decorator allows the user to reap the benefits of graph execution in eager mode, but do be aware that some caveats apply(for example, tf.function prefers TF ops to Python primitives).

Sources: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager
         https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/eager/tf_function